# Azure platform install

Tags: azure

Can we install a version of azure locally? In other words, can we manage an independent azure cloud? I am using the emulator. But I want a real azure system. This question seems meaningless but my professor asked it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you're big enough, then there's the Azure Appliance - http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appliance/

On a smaller scale, many of the Azure facilities are available through "Server 2008 AppFabric" products and Microsoft's management platforms are striving to make private datacenters and public Azure clouds interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't meaningless, as it's important to understand what's offered via Windows Azure. Currently, Windows Azure offers a public cloud. There are a "very" limited number of Windows Azure Appliances that have been built for use by enterprises such as eBay (see the link Stuart provided). However, these are not for general sale, and these are extremely expensive.